# Is there any way to parse a packet in a dictionary format with PyShark?

Tags: python, wireshark, scapy, pyshark

In PyShark, packet information is displayed in a flat list, making it difficult to discern the hierarchical structure of fields, unlike Wireshark which provide a clear hierarchy.
I attached the following images to make my issue clearer. This is how Wireshark is[enter image description here] and this is in PyShark (https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzYBJ.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkBso.png)

I used to work with Scapy which was good in this regard. However, some fields were encoded in formats like `\\x16\\x03\\x01\\x01e\\x01\\x01` and I couldn't translate it to a meaningful information.